# Set different properties for a vim terminal window

Tags: vim

In my `.vimrc`, I set many properties such as `set nu`, ... How can I set properties specifically for terminal windows launched via the command `:term`?

For instance, I would like terminal windows **not** to display line numbers unlike regular vim buffers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/28763/33778), you can use autocommands with `TerminalWinOpen` and `TerminalOpen` to do a command every time terminal is opened. For instance,

`autocmd TerminalWinOpen * setlocal statusline=hello`

will set your statusline bar when a terminal is opened. Autocommand definitions are [here](https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-en/autocmd.html).

Comment: `autocmd TerminalWinOpen * set nonu` works like a charm! Thanks.